# Memory Update for an old laptop

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have an old `HP Pavilion dv6 Series` (*model dv6-1140ej*).

It has 2GB of RAM in 2 sticks. According to the specs, it supports *400Mhz DDR2* memory.

I would like to increase the amount of RAM I have.

Someone told me faster memory sticks (*say 800Mhz*) cannot be used when only *400Mhz* are supported.

This is a bummer, because for some reason 4GB of *400Mhz DDR2* costs about 3-4 times more than a modern DDR2 stick with the same size.

Is this really the case ? Can't a memory stick work in a frequency lower than its optimal ?

Here is the CrucialScan results:

[image: CrucialScan]

And now it's even weirder, with the help of "HP Support Assistant" here are the memory details:

1GB 7F7FFE0000000000 800MHz (X2)

Can I really use **DDR3L-1600 SODIMM** for this old laptop ?

Comment: Check out the tool in the Possible Duplicate post and see what kind of information it gives you.

Comment: edited the information in. Feel free to edit your own questions to add information

Comment: DDR3 cannot fit into a system which accepts DDR2 modules

Comment: Can't find the Possible Duplicate post..

Answer (score 0):

The memory you need is PC2-6400 which is DDR2 at 400Mhz (almost the fastest DDR2).  I'm surprised that Crucial offers a DDR3 option but your computer apparently doesn't support it.

Since there are only two slots and both are used, you will need to replace the ones you have to upgrade.

Note that 32 bit systems limit the available amount to 4GB (in case it applies to you).

To answer your question directly on faster memory being able to run slower, it depends on the actual fabrication of the stick but memory chips are very precise components and if you slow them down too much, they will lose their state before the next cycle.  Modern RAM needs to be refreshed regularly (at the physical level).

Comment: I can only find PC2-6400 at 800Mhz, Will it work ok?

Comment: `PC2-6400` is the correct type but there's either an error in the description or you misread the specs.  Its data rate is 800MT/s but it runs at 400Mhz.

Comment: that's what I found on ebay :/

Comment: If it's really PC2-6400, don't worry about the information they wrongly copied, just take it and it should work.

Comment: On every site I checked it written it's 800Mhz

Comment: It's not my fault sales people don't give a damn about validating the proper terms to use, but that memory is 400Mhz with a data rate of 800MT/s.  You can read it for yourself on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM